# Open a MainActivity2 with Webview, and keep Uri.parse(url) from MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I can open a new activity with WebView by this:

```
  @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".html")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity2.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
```

I would like to open a webview(mainactivity2) with the same url I'm clicking on the MainActivity. So the mainactivity2 should have something like:

```
 myWebView.loadUrl(Uri.parse(url)); but dosent work...
```

Can you please tell me what can I done to achieve this?
Is there any possible to click on the link (WebView - MainActivity, and open then MainActivity2 with the same url?

Answer (score 0):

use [`Bundle`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles)

put `url` inside `Intent`s `Bundle` (`intent.putExtra("url", url);` before `startActivity()` call), read this value in `MainActivity2` in `onCreate` (`String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");`) and load in `WebView`. powodzenia

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I've got it finally:

MainActivity

```
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        
        if (url.endsWith(".html")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", url);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }}
```

MainActivity2

```
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    myWebView.loadUrl(str);
```

Thanks again/works.